# Proof of a fixed point theorem on the disk

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

There is a very nice fixed point theorem which I'd have liked to give to my students :

> Let $n$, $m$ be two integers larger or equal to one. Let $B_n$ be the *open* unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $h$ be an homeomorphism of $B_n$ such that $h^m = id$. Then $h$ has a fixed point.

However, it seems that there is no proof of this general result which does not involve material far beyond their current reach. I was trying to design a simpler proof in dimension $2$, with nothing more evolved that Brouwer's fixed point theorem, invariance of domain, and perhaps (some avatar of) Jordan's curve theorem. I was thinking along these lines :

- Take a large enough closed ball $C$ in $B_2$. Then $K := \bigcup_{k=0}^{m-1} h^k (C)$ is connected.
- Show that complementary of $K$ has one connected component $\Omega$ which borders the disk. Take $K' := \Omega^c$.
- Show that $K'$ is a $h$-invariant simply connected compact. Use a version of Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

However, I have a hard time finding a suitable version of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. I could try to use Jordan-Schoenflies' theorem to conjugate the action of $h$ on $K'$ with the action of some homeomorphism of the closed unit disk, but then, I don't know much about the boundary of $K'$ (well, it is made of pieces of simple loops, but gluing them together seems messy).

Is there a nice and relatively elementary (but maybe completely different) way of proving the result I want ? If there isn't, how can I frame the argument above and where can I find suitable versions of Brouwer or Jordan's theorems to make things as painless as possible ?

Answer (score 2):

(*To make it answered*)

This question has a very good answer on the MO counterpart [Finite-order self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278989/finite-order-self-homeomorphisms-of-mathbfrn) by [Nicholas Kuhn](https://mathoverflow.net/users/102519/nicholas-kuhn):

> There is, naturally, a huge history regarding a basic question like this.  This particular problem was figured out between 1930 and the early 1960's.  The main names are P.A. Smith, Conner, Floyd. Here is a math review to get you going:
>
> [MR0130929](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0130929) (24 #A783) Reviewed
>   Kister, J. M.
>   [Examples of periodic maps on Euclidean spaces without fixed points](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1961-10641-1).
>   Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 67 1961 471–474.
>   54.80 (57.47)
>
> Let $T$ be a homeomorphism of period $r$ on Euclidean space En. The classical result of P. A. Smith is that $T$ has a fixed point if $r$ is prime [Ann. of Math. (2) 35 (1934), 572–578] or a prime power [Amer. J. Math. 63 (1941), 1–8; [MR0003199](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0003199)]. The author settles a question of long standing with the following theorem: If $r$ is not a prime power, then there exists a triangulation $μ$ of $E^{9r}$ and a homeomorphism T of period r on $E^{9r}$ without a fixed point, such that $T$ is simplicial over $μ$. The construction is a modification of an example due to Conner and Floyd [Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 10 (1959), 354–360; [MR0105115](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0105115)].